# i cant seem to know how to transform a Method in a class

Tags: python

here is my code
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOGQ8.png

I don't know how to transform the `self.weekly_salary` into a float so i can multiply

it by another number in `self.monthly_salary`

```
class Employee:
    weeks_in_month = 4
    def __init__(self,w,wd):
        self.wage = w
        self.work_days = wd
    
    def weekly_salary(self):
        return self.wage*8*self.work_days
    
    def monthly_salary(self):
        return self.weeks_in_month *self.weekly_salary
    
    def yearly_salary(self):
        return self.monthly_salary*12
Joe = Employee(13.5,4)
```

I have tried using `__int__` or `__float__` on the method but it all comes back as an error

please help i am still a newbie

Comment: You need to _call_ the function: `self.weeks_in_month * self.weekly_salary()` if you want to multiply by the value it returns. Alternatively you can make it a property by placing the decorator `@property`  on the line before `def weekly_salary(self)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Employee:
    weeks_in_month = 4
    def __init__(self, w, wd):
        self.wage = w
        self.work_days = wd

    def month_in_year(self):
        return 12

    def weekly_salary(self):
        #print('Weekly salary', self.wage * 8 * self.work_days)
        return float(self.wage * 8 * self.work_days)

    def monthly_salary(self):
        #print('Monthly Salary',self.weeks_in_month * self.weekly_salary())
        return float(self.weeks_in_month * self.weekly_salary())

    def yearly_salary(self):
        print('Yearly Salary', self.monthly_salary() * self.month_in_year())
        return self.monthly_salary() * 12


Joe = Employee(13.5, 4)


Joe.yearly_salary()
```

You forgot to call self.monthly_salary() instead you tried to subtract an int with a method directly which gives typeerror

Comment: You are Welcome :)